# Token Passport Users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm new to building APIs, and I'm using Laravel and some packages, like Passport.

In this project I'm creating an API to communicate with a mobile app and make some tasks, like creating users and adding some information related to the users.

I'm already getting the idea of how it works with tokens, and I already have almost everything done. My only question is, for example, before I create a register user to receive the token I have other information being presented in the mobile app, like news, and some listing information that is not needed to login or register.

In my API I already have these routes ready, but I cant access this information because I need a token.

How do iI handle this situation? When I need to access information, where I cant present it?

Answer (score 0):

Use your **controllers** to retrieve the data you need from your database and then return a response with the data and create a token for the user:

```
...
$status = 200;
$response = [
   'data'  => Your data (user info, listings, news...),
   'token' => Auth::user()->createToken("YourTokenName")->accessToken,
];

return response()->json($response, $status);
```

Then you could store that token in **localStorage**:

```
axios.post('your-api-route')
.then((response) => {
   localStorage.setItem(`${"YourTokenName"}.jwt`, response.token);
   ...
})
```

And finally attach that token to the **api routes** that require **authentication**:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(`${YourTokenName}.jwt`);
```